# How to use jinja2 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, flask, error-handling, jinja2

I am trying to use jinja in javascript but it throws error

[this is what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZtcW.png)

[Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8mkM.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put quotes around your jinja

```
window.onload = start("{{ board|safe }}");
```

Comment: actually now it is taken as a string by js but i want to use it as an array